# How to display toolbar transparent in parallax android

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I want to use Parallax Listview and Im referring this link to apply for my project: 
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-header-parallax-in-android

I have added Toolbar in Activity but it Toolbar is not display

My activity class:

```
public class DetailListCarActivityDemo extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
private View heroImageView;
private View stickyViewSpacer;
private int MAX_ROWS = 20;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_list_car_demo);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    /* Initialise list view, hero image, and sticky view */
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    heroImageView = findViewById(R.id.heroImageView);
    /* Inflate list header layout */
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_detail_category, null);
    /* Add list view header */
    listView.addHeaderView(listHeader);
    /* Handle list View scroll events */
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            /* Check if the first item is already reached to top.*/
            if (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
                View firstChild = listView.getChildAt(0);
                int topY = 0;
                if (firstChild != null) {
                    topY = firstChild.getTop();
                }
                // int heroTopY = stickyViewSpacer.getTop();
                // stickyView.setY(Math.max(0, heroTopY + topY));
                /* Set the image to scroll half of the amount that of ListView */
                heroImageView.setY(topY * 0.5f);
            }
        }
    });
    /* Populate the ListView with sample data */
    List<String> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        modelList.add("List item " + i);
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_detail_category, modelList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
}
```

activity_detail_list_car_demo.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_translucent" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/heroImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mercedes"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#9E9E9E"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">
</ListView>
```

@drawable/background_toolbar_translucent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="@color/black_alpha_40"/>
</shape>
```

@color/black_alpha_40.xml:

```
<color name="black_alpha_40">#66000000</color>
```

**UPDATED:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<ListView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#9E9E9E"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_translucent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/heroImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mercedes"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</ListView>
```

As you see my toolbar is transparent, and it same position with image on top, toolbar is front, image is behind.

How to display toolbar and display as I have described as above

Answer (score 1):

Add layout_behaviour in your ListView.

> > android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> >     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
> >     android:id="@+id/listview" />

Preferably I'll tell. Use collapsible toolbar instead of doing this much of stuff.

Comment: thank for your reply, add in activity_detail_list_car_demo.xml, isn't it ?

Comment: Dude, use collapsible toolbar and add your Toolbar and heroImageView inside that and use layout behaviour in listview. I'll surely work well.

Comment: Sorry Im a newbiew, I have updated and it happened an exception, maybe im wrong, please review for me

Comment: http://www.feelzdroid.com/2015/08/collapsing-toolbars-android-example.html

Comment: I will try and back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CollapsingToolbarLayout.You have to put Toolbar inside CollaspingToolbarLayout. here [example](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)